# Reuso de conexões no Nodejs + Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou começando agora com Node e utilizei o Mongoose para fazer minhas conexões com o banco de dados em MongoDB.
Eu coloquei 1 log na minha aplicação, para toda vez que abrir a conexão ele printar nesse log.

O que acontece:
Toda vez que alguem chama 1 URL minha, a minha aplicação em Node abre uma conexão com o MongoDB, isso é normal e correto?
Ou seja, se 1.000 acessarem meu site, vai haver 1000 conexões abertas? Existe alguma forma de melhorar isso e evitar problemas, ou isso é normal para este ambiente?

Para cada Model meu, eu tenho 1 código desse tipo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var database = require('../config/database');
var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true }};
mongoOptions.user = database.user;
mongoOptions.pass = database.pass;

console.log('Running mongoose version %s', mongoose.version);

mongoose.connect(database.url, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
  if (err) { 
    console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + database.url + '. ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log ('Successfully connected to: ' + database.url);
  }
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var citySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: String,
    uf: String,
    dtRequest: Date,
    active: Boolean,
    loc: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('City', citySchema);

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error);

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  db.close(function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: Podes colocar o teu código?

Comment: Atualizado com 1 das entidades/model meu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conexão com o banco de dados deve ficar no arquivo principal do projeto, aquele que o node vai executar, logo, a conexão só será feita uma vez.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo é o seu arquivo principal, o app.js, responsável pelas rotas e configurações do projeto:

```
const express = require('express');
const database = require('../config/database');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

const mongoOptions = { 
    db: { safe: true },
    user: database.user,
    pass: database.pass
};

mongoose.connect(database.url, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + database.url + '. ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log ('Successfully connected to: ' + database.url);
    }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

O código abaixo é o seu model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const citySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: String,
    uf: String,
    dtRequest: Date,
    active: Boolean,
    loc: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('City', citySchema);
```

Quando você executar um *node app.js* a conexão será iniciada uma única vez, e vai permanecer assim até que o processo seja finalizado ou ocorra algum erro.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, aparentemente deu tudo certo. Vou fazer mais testes aqui. Uma duvida, pq vc usa const no lugar de var?

Comment: Sei que já faz um tempo que o comentário acima foi publicado, mas vou responder para ajudar outras pessoas que possam vir a ter a mesma dúvida.

Marlon, uso const no lugar do var pois na última versão do JavaScript (ES6), surgiu o const e o let. O const é usado para constantes e o let para variáveis. O let é bem parecido com o var, porém com algumas diferenças no escopo. Uso o const pois é o que o padrão do ESLint determina no prefer-const.

Para mais informações, pesquise por ES6 e ESLint. Abraços!